# boost::signals2 still emits signals to an object where the reference died

Tags: c++, boost

I am currently playing aroung with signals/slots and try to write my own little lib for a micro controller. In this context I had an error, where when I passed an object (context) and a member function as the slot function, the slot was still called despite the object being dead.

Consider the following example:

```
#include <boost/signals2.hpp>
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
  void does() {
    std::cout << "i: " << i << " addr: " << (uint64_t)&*this << std::endl;
  }
  int i = 0;
};


int main()
{
  boost::signals2::signal<void()> sig;

  {
    A a;
    std::cout << "addr: " << (uint64_t)&a << std::endl;
    sig.connect( [&a]{a.does();});
    sig();
  }
  {
    A a;
    a.i = 3;
  }
  sig();
}
```

*output:*

```
addr: 140722327054036
i: 0 addr: 140722327054036
i: 0 addr: 140722327054036
```

First cout is normal. Second one emitted through the signal is also okay. But the third is pretty strange. For me since the first `a` died and I create the second one with `i = 3` normally it should print `3` in the second signal since the stack variable should be fully overwritten.

This is btw the same problem I want to achieve in my lib. I want to keep track of references. But I think this is not possible, without inducing some kind of signal inside the destructor probably.

So what would be a good approach to solve that problem? Only thing I can think of is Pub/Sub pattern. This feeld like mostly the same. But I kinda don't like the fact, that each class which can catch a signal has to be derived by a Subscriber class.

Comment: That's a problem with any signal-slot library, I know: If receiver dies without notifying emitter somehow, the emitter has a dangling reference/pointer or whatever. The solutions are in any case similar: Either store the connection (`boost::signal2::connection`) to remove handler from emitter when receiver is destroyed, or automate this, e.g. by deriving `struct A` from `boost::signals2::trackable`.

Comment: I would've made this an answer but my practical experiences span sigc++ and Qt signals as well as DIY implementations but I never used `boost::signal2`. However, the principles are always the same... ;-) Have a look at [Connection Management](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/signals2/tutorial.html#id-1.3.37.4.6) and [Automatic Connection Management](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/signals2/tutorial.html#signals2.tutorial.connection-management).

Comment: I see, so practically I have to destroy the connection like keeping track of a pointer allocated with new. That actually makes sense. I will dig into `trackable` thanks for the hint, I tried reading the boost implementation but it's pretty hard. But now I surely know where I have to look. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Digging a bit deeper, I have to admit `boost::signal2::trackable` seems to be old-fashioned: _Automatic connection management is now achieved through the use of shared_ptr/weak_ptr and signals2::slot::track(), as described in the tutorial. However, the old (thread-unsafe) Boost.Signals scheme of automatic connection management is still supported via the boost::signals2::trackable class._

Comment: Yepp. boost is definitely sophisticated. The tutorials in doc. might help or looking for examples somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a scoped connection to manage the life time of a connection.

```
scoped_connection keep = sig.connect([&a] { a.does(); });
```

See **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e516ef9b9f0691fb)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/signals2.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace bs = boost::signals2;

static inline int genid() { static int s_current = 0; return ++s_current; }

struct A {
    int i = genid();
    void operator()() const { std::cout << "i: " << i << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
    bs::signal<void()> sig;

    {
        A a;
        bs::scoped_connection keep = sig.connect(a);
        sig();
    }
    {
        A a[100] = {};
    }
    sig();
}
```

Just prints

```
i: 1
```

Comment: That is also pretty interesting, thanks for that I mark my answer as solved.